# OS name for 22.04-LTS in Azure templates

Tags: azure

Azure does not have any 22.04-LTS OS image version.

I checked with this command:

```
az vm image list-skus --publisher Canonical --offer UbuntuServer --location westus | more
```

It does show 16.04-LTS and 18.04-LTS but does not show any 22.04-LTS OS at all.

So I currently get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
        "message": "The template deployment 'BaseImageVMDeployment_dev-westus_20230323204936' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'dcdd26b0-daad-44c1-a1a7-b43a205f7de6'. See inner errors for details.",
        "details": [{
            "code": "InvalidParameter",
            "target": "imageReference",
            "message": "The following list of images referenced from the deployment template are not found: Publisher: Canonical, Offer: UbuntuServer, Sku: 22.04-LTS, Version: latest. Please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage for instructions on finding available images."
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask the Azure people. Azure is a Microsoft product,

Answer (score 2):

Newer Ubuntu releases (after 18.04 LTS) are published under dedicated offers.

For 22.04 LTS you should use:

| Architecture | URN | SKU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMD64 Hyper-V Generation: Gen1 | `Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy:22_04-lts:latest` | `22_04-lts` |
| AMD64 Hyper-V Generation: Gen2 | `Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy:22_04-lts-gen2:latest` | `22_04-lts-gen2` |
| Arm64 Hyper-V Generation: Gen2 | `Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy:22_04-lts-arm64:latest` | `22_04-lts-arm64` |

This is all documented on Canonical's website under [server docs](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/find-ubuntu-images-on-azure).